# Use string as public string name?

Tags: c#, string, class, static, public

I have the file: dvars.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace GSM
{
    public static class dvar
    {
            static int _pspeed = 2;

            public static int pspeed
            {
                get
                {
                    return _pspeed;
                }
                set
                {
                    _pspeed = value;
                }
            }
    }

}
```

I want to be able to use a string to define it for example(in a different file i want to set the dvar.pspeed using a string as the variable name):

```
string mystring = "pspeed";
dvar.mystring = 1;
```

Does anybody know how I could go about this?

Comment: question:  would you expect dvar.pspeed == 1 at this point?  The problem is you're not setting a variable name but rather a property value.  Variables and properties are very different animals.  I think you're talking about aliasing your property names.  Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could you use reflection to do this.

```
String mystring = "pspeed";
PropertyInfo pi = typeof(dvar).GetProperty(mystring);
pi.SetValue(dvar, 1, new Object[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, however you could wrap a dictionary using an indexer:

```
public static class Dvar 
{
    private static IDictionary<string, int> map = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public static int this[string key]
    {
        get { return map[key]; }
        set { map[key] = value; }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Dvar["pspeed"] = 1;
```

Comment: @Fraser - Yes that's also possible, if he only has one property then your answer is more likely to be what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the Int32.Prase() method or (TryParse() if you need to validate it).

Comment: Fyi: TryParse won't let you use a property as an out parameter.

Comment: i want to set the dvar.pspeed using a string as the variable name